# Modifying root beer recipe to alcoholic variant?

Tags: root-beer

I recently obtained a bottle caper, some sassafrass bark chips, and some root beer extract flavoring from a coupling moving out. It also contained a recipe for rootbeer(non-alcoholic), listed below:

Beginners Quick Bottling Recipe: Uses 2 used 2-L plastic soda bottles

1. 1/8 teaspoon dry yeast, in a 6oz cup of warm water
2. 2 & 1/4 cups sugar, 1 tablespoon extract
3. Mix in 1 gallon container
4. Pour 1/2 mixture in each soda bottle
5. Top off each bottle with plain water to within 1 & 1/2 inches of top
6. use resealable cap and shake
7. store at room temp in the 70's for 4-6 days

**How would I modify this recipe to allow for the soda to be alcoholic AND also be stored in smaller used beer glass bottles?**

Doing some of my own research, and only having made "hooch" before I assume that I could simply add more yeast and sugar to allow for more alcohol, but then regardless how would I deal with a loss of carbonation when decanting my product from the 2 L bottles to the smaller glass bottles, or the possible risk of still active yeast? I do not have access to alot of fancy equipment like kegs or carbonators, not even a siphon.

Comment: @Keystone       I saw that, and I just would prefer a modification to the recipe above. My homebrewing skills are not that great.

Comment: I feel as though this has already been said (see the marked question), but if you extend your process by adding an alcohol fermentation stage before you bottle, then you will produce alcoholic root beer. When I first started brewing I did this with a ginger beer recipe and it worked well. I might add that I am partial to less sugar. As for carbonation, your alcohol stage will produce too much CO2 (bucket and airlock) to be decent for carbonating, so I suggest that you bottle with a little added sugar for carbonating and leave if for a month or two before chilling it.

Comment: @Keystone       Thanks, so if I understand, I could make the root beer in a 2L vessel of some sort, let it ferment( ~21 days total?), and then bottle the ferment into glass beer bottles with a little sugar? (a pinch?)

Comment: That is the right idea. I'm not sure about the 21 days or pinch measures. The fermentation will stop on its own and you can monitor it if you get a 2L growler and airlock + bung. You will see when it is done because the airlock stops bubbling. The measure of sugar for bottling depends on how much fizz you want, I would recommend 8-12 grams/L, but I'm guessing.

PS: howtobrew.com is an excellent resource that you should take the time to absorb.

Comment: @Keystone       Sorry for the 20 questions, but could i do without the growler? At the moment it is out of my price range (student), and from what I read it only keeps carbonation high, which I can live without (to a degree)

Comment: I guess a 2-3L orange juice bottle would work. The only critical part is the airlock, which probably costs a few dollars at most, and a good seal between it and the bottle. PS: I brewed with goon bags in uni. Glue a tiny hose into the cap of the beer goon and dunk the other end in another goon filled with a small amount of water, tape them together over a hanger. Makes a foamy mess in the second goon which you have to clean out every little while, and tends to be bad beer, but on a strict budget it works.

Comment: @Keystone       But why is the goon even needed? Cant I do without it? I was hoping just to use a bottle to ferment, and a airlock to block any intruding air.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25230/discussion-between-keystone-and-ro-siv).